# What is the difference between by and summary?

Tags: r, variables, output, mean, summary

maybe someone can answer my question.
What is the difference between the following writings? In my case I am interested to know mean but I get different numbers.

```
> by(wcomp$numbf.y, wcomp$partw2, summary, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Mean 2.473

```
summary(wcomp$numbf.y, wcomp$partw2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Mean 2.573

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you publish/link the dataset?

Comment: The data set is private.
It basically says that people named a number of friends 0-5 <- numbf
and they participated in survey wave 2 yes = 1, no = 0 <-partw2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your data: `by` applies a function (`summary`) to a vector (`wcomp$numbf.y`) **by** a group (`wcomp$partw2`).

Whereas `summary`creates a summary of your data (kinda ignoring the second argument).

See also this MWE (Ive used the `mtcars` dataset and set some values to `NA`:

```r
df <- mtcars
df[c(1, 5), c("cyl", "mpg")] <- NA
head(df)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           NA  NA  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   NA  NA  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

by(df$mpg, df$cyl, summary)
#> df$cyl: 4
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   21.40   22.80   26.00   26.66   30.40   33.90 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> df$cyl: 6
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   17.80   18.38   19.45   19.53   20.68   21.40 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> df$cyl: 8
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   10.40   14.30   15.20   14.82   15.80   19.20

summary(df$mpg, df$cyl)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
#>   10.40   15.28   19.20   20.11   22.80   33.90       2
summary(df$mpg)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
#>   10.40   15.28   19.20   20.11   22.80   33.90       2
summary(df$cyl)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
#>   4.000   4.000   6.000   6.133   8.000   8.000       2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

We see that the mean values are all different, as we are calculating different means: once for all obs (in the summary call), and when using the `by` call, we calculate the summary per group (cyl).

We also see that the second argument to `summary()` is ignored.

Does that answer your question?

If you are only interested in the mean, try

```r
mean(df$mpg, na.rm = TRUE) #< na.rm needed here!
#> [1] 20.10667

by(df$mpg, df$cyl, mean)
#> df$cyl: 4
#> [1] 26.66364
#> ------------------------------------------------------ 
#> df$cyl: 6
#> [1] 19.53333
#> ------------------------------------------------------ 
#> df$cyl: 8
#> [1] 14.82308
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, this is the answer I was looking for.
As you can guess I am a beginner ...is there a good resource you can recommend?

Comment: No worries, that what we are here for. I am a big fan of [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/), alternatively, I can recommend the [RStudio beginner page](https://education.rstudio.com/learn/beginner/). Last but not least, do you mind accepting the answer as a solution? Thanks

Comment: Yes, sure. Do you mean the vote button or is there another option?